# Sequential ID Generation for asynchronous database insert operations

Tags: c#, asynchronous, foreach, task-parallel-library

It is a typical problem I am facing. 
I want to insert 2k rows in database using asynchronous TPL where each record has an **incremental sequential key.**

I have 3 layers in my Service Side :

Here is what follows :

**In Service Side:**

First I get the max seq key from database.

```
Data.Upload.UploadDetails gd = new Data.Upload.UploadDetails();

try
{

    var Max_seq_key = gd.getGroupMembershipSeqKeyDetails();
```

This **getGroupMembershipSeqKeyDetails** method is in **DAL layer** which goes like :

```
    public long getGroupMembershipSeqKeyDetails()
    {
        Repository rep = new Repository();
        string strSPQuery = string.Empty;
        List<long> listSeqKey = new List<long>();
        long strMaxSeqKey = -1;

        try
        {
            listSeqKey = rep.ExecuteSqlQuery<Int64>(SQL.Upload.UploadDetails.getMaxSeqKeySQL()).ToList();
            strMaxSeqKey = listSeqKey[0] != null ? listSeqKey[0] : strMaxSeqKey;
            return strMaxSeqKey;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return strMaxSeqKey;
        }
    }
```

So in service layer I get the max seq key from database.

Now I want to insert 2k records using below statement from **service side.**

```
            foreach (var grpMem in input.ListGroupMembershipUploadDetailsInput.GroupMembershipUploadInputList)
            {
                try
                {
                    Task.Run(() => gd.insertGroupMembershipUploadDetails(grpMem,
                                                    input.ListChapterUploadFileDetailsInput, ++Max_seq_key, ++Max_grp_seq_key, Lst_com_unit_key, trans_key));
                }
```

But this **++Max_seq_key** is not always guaranteed.

Sometimes I get results like in database:

[image]

How can I make sure this incremental seq key is always greater than 1 than the previous inserted record which is of course running on a different thread ?

Comment: As Dennis' answer states, best is to have the DB generate each number. But as for `++`: it's a known misconception that this is an thread safe operation, but it's not atomic and therefore not thread safe. For thread safe incrementing, you can use `Interlocked.Increment`

Comment: `getMaxSeqKeySQL` has a bug. Can't say what it is because the code is missing.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I make sure this incremental seq key is always greater than 1

The obvious answer is "do not generate keys at client side".
Just forget about `max + 1` approach.

Use database capabilities to generate unique keys, like [identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) columns or [sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx).

Links are MS SQL-specific, but you can easily find the same documentation for another RDBMS, e.g. here's one for [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm).

P.S. Your "async" code isn't truly async - repository must be rewritten in the async way.